# Mudar CSS com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Possuo este código:

```js
function convert() {
  var bord = window.document.getElementById("borda")
  var b = Number(bord.value)
  document.getElementById("caixa").style.widht = "10px"
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
<form>
    <input id="borda" name="borda" type="number">
    <input type="button" value="BOTÃO" onclick="convert()">
</form>
```

Ao clicar no botão o elemento não muda de tamanho.

Comment: Se só quer resolver o problema imediato: `document.getElementById('idDoElemento').style.width = "200px";`

Comment: sou iniciante, mas segue o codigo aí                                                                         

    <div id="caixa" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    <form>
        <input id="borda" name="borda" type="number">
        <input type="button" value="BOTÃO" onclick="convert()">
    </form>

    <script>
        function convert() {
            var bord = window.document.getElementById("borda")
            var b = Number(bord.value)

            document.getElementById("caixa").style.widht = "10px"
        }
    </script>

Comment: pra pegar a largura `var largura = window.document.getElementById("borda").value`. Se não tiver o "px" nela precisa de um `largura = ( largura + 'px' );` . depois usa a variável no lugar do 200px do meu exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chegou perto, basicamente enroscou em erro de sintaxe.

- `style.widht` está grafado errado, é `width`.

daí é só concatenar o valor com `variavel + "px"` (a unidade que achar pertinente para o seu caso)

Segue código ajustado e simplificado:

```js
function convert() {
  var largura = window.document.getElementById("borda").value;
  document.getElementById("caixa").style.width = largura+'px';
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
<form>
    <input id="borda" name="borda" type="number" value="200">
    <input type="button" value="BOTÃO" onclick="convert()">
</form>
```

Note que no seu código original faltam as `;` no final das linhas. Em certas situações o JS até "entende", mas é bom evitar ambiguidades.

Comment: Lindoooo Valeu!!!

Comment: @Lucas se a resposta resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor.

Comment: Como marco que a resposta está certa?